# How to preserve the name of the remoteUser while reverse proxy?

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, reverse-proxy, remote, http-headers

I am using a software which enables me to log my operations and one the things it is loggin is the name of the remote user.

Neverthless, I have a little problem since I am working on a secured network, which gets Http requests from the port 9200 and sends it to 9201 so while doing the reverse proxy I am losing the name of the user.

Do I have any configuration to do in order to not to lose the remote user?

**EDIT:** I am using the config as followed;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} ^[a-z].*
RewriteRule ^\/(.*)$ /%{LA-U:REMOTE_USER}/$1
```

Comment: Your question lacks quite a bit of details on how your authentication is configured and what exactly needs to be forwarded, but sometimes using [**`proxy-chain-auth`**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_http.html) is an option.

Comment: I am trying to send remote_user. I have put RequestHeader set REMOTE_USER %{REMOTE_USER}s
  SetEnv proxy-chain-auth On
ProxyPassInterpolateEnv On

but still I can not get remote_use

Comment: @HBruijn I am using that auth in both reverse proxy and proxy but, I am losing the user while the reverse proxy. Any idea ?